# mod_rewrite - change top level domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im trying to find out an issue with the following mod_rewrite Rule:

On my Account on "Strato" (Hoster) the Rule is working, however it is not working on "1und1" (another Hoster). Is there anything wrong with that rule?

```
# Rewrite Rule
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*original-domain.de [NC]
 RewriteRule /* http://new-subdomain.anotherdomain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
# End Rewrite Rule
```

Is there perhaps another or even better way to get the redirect done?

The Goal is that a User who is visiting http://www.original-domain.de (with or without www.) should see the content of http://new-subdomain.anotherdomain.de but the original-domain Adress still stays in the Adressbar of the Browser. In other words, the User won't even recognize that he got redirected.

And, another Question: What stands the [P] for after the Rewrite Rule? If i change it to [L] the redirect works but with the new-subdomain.anotherdomain.de Adress beeing displayed in the Browser? Couldn't find a Website that describes that properly.

Thanks for your help in advance!